# Help with removing duplicate reversed pairs in relational algebra

Tags: relational-theory

I have a listing of data that contains duplicate reversed pairs and I need to remove them.. Call them, name1 and name2. Where I have Tom and Mike, and Mike and Tom, such that this single pair is being counted twice.

```
 name1 | name2
-------|-------
 Tom   | Mike
 Pete  | Jenny
 Bill  | Jenny
 Joe   | Mary
 Mike  | Tom
 Jenny | Pete
 Jenny | Bill
 Mary  | Joe
 Linda | Jenny
```

The List was a product of an initial match of student with guidance counselor,  then the product of the student/counselor and counselor table, which resulted in a longer list and was able to reduce to the pairs above. But, now can't get rid of the duplicates.

While I might have made a mistake in combing the tables that made the pairing, I am stuck with that table for now.. This is a listing of student paired with guidance counselors.

Is there a way to de-dup the list, or do I need to start over?

Comment: Which database system (RDBMS) are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to return an existing combination, e.g. if there's only *Tom,Mike* do you need to return exactly this or is *Mike,Tom* also ok?

```
-- order of columns doesn't matter
SELECT DISTINCT
   CASE WHEN name1 > name2 THEN name2 ELSE name1 END as name1,
   CASE WHEN name1 < name2 THEN name2 ELSE name1 END as name2
FROM tab;

-- order of columns is maintained
SELECT DISTINCT name1,name2 -- DISTINCT might not be needed
FROM tab AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM tab AS t2
  WHERE t1.name1 = t2.name2
    AND t1.name2 = t2.name1
    AND t1.name1 > t2.name1)
;
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2676a8/1)

If you want to delete those rows you might us the 2nd logic, the actual syntax depends on your DBMS:

```
DELETE --change to SELECT * to see which rows will be deleted
FROM tab AS t1
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM tab AS t2
  WHERE t1.name1 = t2.name2
    AND t1.name2 = t2.name1
    AND t1.name1 > t2.name1)
;
```

Comment: Thanks... Found an article on how to so this in SQL Studio, reverse engineered into relational algebra. Here is the code, a_NoDup_No2ndPair:= 

 project  lname1, lname2  (select (ssn1=ssn2 )  and (lname1 < lname2) (a_NoDup));
Thanks for the feedback.. I think I had tried this early on, but had the syntax wrong, took lots of fiddling as WinRDBi does not help as much as sql studio when it comes to syntax...